# SQL SERVER: Accessing Cosmos-Db in SSMS via ODBC

Tags: sql-server, odbc, ssms, azure-cosmosdb, linked-server

I'm attempting to follow the guide [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/odbc-driver#:%7E:text=You%20can%20query%20Azure%20Cosmos,and%20connect%20to%20the%20server.) which shows how to link an azure cosmos-db as a linked server via ODBC. I have created the ODBC links to the remote cosmos-db in both x64 and x86 flavours. These appear to connect without issue when checking from within the ODBC Admin console and I can even see the data when setting up a schema, however I am unable to create a working linked server as I get the following error when testing the connection ..

"[microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"

I Believe this is maybe because I have SQL Express installed and the "**Providers**" folder is missing from the "**Linked Server**" folder. I am therefore assuming that I do not have the necessary providers installed on the SQL Server Instance running locally.

I have attempted to install both the [OLE DB Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and the [ODBC Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15), however these have not helped.

[image]

[image]

Comment: If this is only for dev and testing, use Developer Edition instead of SQL Express.

Comment: I thought these were one and the same these days. I'm running SQL Server 15.0.2080.9 and SSMS v18.11.1.

Comment: Developer Edition has all the same features as Enterprise without db size limits. I'm not suggesting that will fix your linked server issue. The Providers folder should not be empty. FWIW, this is the undocumented proc SSMS uses to enumerate the OLE DB providers: `EXEC master.dbo.xp_enum_oledb_providers;`. Try running that ad-hoc.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman this proved to be really useful as all of the providers are listed. Maybe I'll try uninstalling and reinstalling the latest Developer Edition and see if that helps. Thanks again

Comment: I don't know why SSMS doesn't show them if the proc returns the list. I think you could create the linked server using T-SQL, specifying the MSDASQL provider and connection string with the ODBC driver and connection string keywords.

Comment: Yeah have done this .. and still get this error. I'm stumpted !